# Как запускать автозапуск мелодии на определенной странице?

Tags: javascript

Стоит задача запускать мелодию на главное странице.

Выдает такую вот ошибку `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Но если перейти на другую страницу, а затем снова вернутся на главную, то ошибка пропадает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```js
var currentpage = document.location.href;
var mainpage = 'http://lawyer/';
console.log(currentpage);
console.log(mainpage);

if (currentpage == mainpage) {
  document.getElementById('audio').play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio">
 <source  src="/audio/1.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276718/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-the-play-request-was-interru - посмотри вот тут. Похоже на твою проблему.

Comment: В том, что текущие версии браузеров блокируют автовоспроизведение, и происходит это нестабильно, т. е., в некоторых труднопредсказуемых случаях блокировка не срабатывает. У меня Ваш код вызывает ошибку и после возвращения на главную. Поэтому сейчас для автовоспроизведения можно использовать старый добрый тег <embed>...</embed>. Ещё не совсем по теме - не проще будет элемент аудио содержать только на главной и не делать кодом проверку, главная это или нет?

Comment: большое спасибо за подсказку. увы такой вариант с кодом только на главной рассматривал, но по задумке немного не подходит. Но все равно спасибо за помощь и с Новым Годом!